# MySql Error: Too Many Connections

Tags: mysql

Since yesterday I get the error.
How much could be contacted?

```
  Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Too many connections in /home/----/public_html/----/class_db.php on line 85
```

Comment: Read this -> [mysql.com: Too Many Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) and this -> [php.net: mysql_close](http://uk3.php.net/mysql_close)

Comment: It means what it says there are too many open connections to the database, either your program is making too many and not closing them, or possibly if you are on shared hosting someone else is.

Comment: Thank you. The end of all the mysql connections writes: 'code mysql_close();'

Comment: I use shared hosting. I think it is due.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `/etc/my.cnf` or wherever your MySQL configuration file is located. Increase `max_connections`. The default number depends on your version of MySQL, but it is probably set to `100`.

Comment: Would it not be wise to see why so many connections are open first ? just raising the limit won't fix any potential issues

Comment: The my shared hosting, `code etc/my.cnf` data nope. Only  etc/ example.com and ftpquota current file.

Answer (score 0):

You should monitor your connections and close them if they are not used anymore. Otherwise you could decrease the value of the [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) server variable, it will help to close them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth knowing that if you run out of usable disc space on your server partition or drive, that this will also cause MySQL to return with this error.

If you're sure it's not the actual number of users connected then the next step is to check that you have free and usable space on your MySQL server drive/partition.

I found this out this morning, when a backup system oversaved and crammed my drive full of backups, running out of disc space and causing this error :-/ .